# Get the latest Windows 2012R2 base AMI id using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ami, aws-powershell

Is there a way to get the latest Windows 2012R2 base AMI id using aws cli?

Something like `Get-EC2ImageByName -Names WINDOWS_2012R2_BASE` in Powershell. I want to use it in Linux.

I have tried fetching AMI id with 
`aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --filters "Name=name,Values=Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-Base-*"` but it feels like a hack. Is there a better way to do this like in Powershell?

Comment: nop, using the CLI, its the best method as documented by aws http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html#finding-an-ami-aws-cli - the powershell has added additional method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "hack" you described is the correct way to retrieve these in AWS CLI.  As a matter of fact, this is what the PowerShell Tools' `Get-EC2ImageByName` does behind the scenes; it maps a raw AMI name (exposed by `ShowFilter` parameter) to a pre-defined name pattern, exposed by `AllAvailable` parameter.

You can see this by listing the `ShowFilter` parameter; the first result matches the name value you've listed:

```
C:/ > get-ec2imagebyname -ShowFilters

Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-Base*
Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-SQL_2014_SP1_Express*
Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-SQL_2014_SP1_Standard*
Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-SQL_2014_SP1_Web*
Windows_Server-2012-RTM-English-64Bit-Base*
...
```

To get only the latest Windows 2012 R2 AMI ID back from AWS CLI, sort your query by CreationDate and limit to only the last result.

**Example:**

```
aws ec2 describe-images \
    --owners 'amazon' \
    --filters 'Name=name,Values=Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-Base*' \
    --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-1].[ImageId]' \
    --output 'text'
```

**Output:**

```
ami-11e84107
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS CLI Documentation - describe-images](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html)
- [AWS PowerShell Documentation - Get-EC2ImageByName](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2ImageByName.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)